# Where can we use Jasmine Matchers for JavaScript Testing

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have tried to use Jasmine Matchers and it does give me a great in depth detail about the error messages. The unit tests also become meaningful but when it comes to distributed and large scale projects, I'm not sure how the matchers play a good role.

Below is my matcher example for a sample script.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.addMatchers({
        toBeAGoodInvestment: toBeAGoodInvestment
    });
});

function toBeAGoodInvestment() {
    return {
        compare: function (actual, expected) {
            // Matcher Definition
            var result = {};
            result.pass = actual.isGood();

            if (actual.isGood()) {
                result.message = 'Expected investment to be a bad investment';
            } else {
                result.message = 'Expected investment to be a good investment';
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and the spec file is as below

```
describe('Investment', function () {
   var stock, investment;
   beforeEach(function () {
      stock = new Stock();
      investment = new Investment({
         stock: stock,
         shares: 100,
         sharePrice: 20
      });
   });

   it('should be of a stock', function () {
      expect(investment.stock).toBe(stock);
   });

   it('should have invested shares quantity', function () {
      expect(investment.shares).toBe(100)
   });

   it('should have the share paid price', function () {
      expect(investment.sharePrice).toBe(20);
   });

   it('should have a cost', function () {
      expect(investment.cost).toBe(2000)
   });

   describe('when its stock share price valorizes', function () {
      beforeEach(function () {
         stock.sharePrice = 40;
      });

      it('should have a positive roi', function () {
         expect(investment.roi()).toEqual(1);
      });

      it('should be a good investment', function () {
         expect(investment.isGood()).toEqual(true);
      });

      it('matcher: should be a good investment', function () {
         expect(investment).toBeAGoodInvestment();
      });
   });
});
```

I've added both the default Jasmine matchers unit test cases as well as custom matcher. I am unsure how this is helpful in a larger project. If there is any principle guidance behind how to use these matchers then it would be great

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct and clear correlation between a size of a project and the usefulness of writing custom Jasmine matchers.

Introducing custom Jasmine matchers can have multiple positive impacts on the quality of the test code, its readability and compactness regardless of a size of a codebase:

- making a custom matcher for a common assertion check helps not to violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
- it is a ["Extract Method"](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring method as well

It is though the author's responsibility to make the matcher *provide a clear and understandable feedback* in case an assertion error happens. I'm not sure how clear the "good" and "bad" investment rules are in your case, but, on the first glance, I would say errors like:

> Expected investment to be a good investment

are not clear enough - compare it to a, for instance:

> Expected investment to be a good investment. Shared price is below configured minimum (30).

In other words, *when it fails, give as much information as you have, just tell everything.*

---

Another often overlooked point is that *custom matcher should be introducing any side effects* or change the object under assertion. This may lead to surprises which would be difficult to debug.